# Running TestNG using Gradle not working when suites are mentioned in build.gradle

Tags: gradle

I need to run TestNG using Gradle and I am new with Gradle.

I am able to run it without stating the testng.xml and with using the `includeGroups` property.
I am not able to run it when I add the `suites` property.

My testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite allow-return-values="true" name="sanitySuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="1" verbose="1">
    <test name="Role Page" >
        <parameter name="userName" value="asdasdasd@asdasdasd.com"/>
        <parameter name="password" value="asdasdasdasd"/>
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="roles"/>
                <!--<exclude name="roles"/>-->
            </run>

        </groups>

        <packages>
            <package name=".*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.rhythmone.fusion'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
        automationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
        automationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('swaggerVersion', "2.9.2")
}

sourceSets {
    automationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/main/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/main/resources')
    }
}

task automationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.automationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.automationTest.runtimeClasspath
    useTestNG() {
       suites "src/main/resources/testng.xml"
    }
}

dependencies {
        compile 'org.testng:testng:7.1.0'
        compile 'org.testng:testng:6.4.13'
        compile 'io.appium:java-client:7.1.0'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile group: 'org.jasypt', name: 'jasypt', version: '1.9.2'
    compile group: 'de.qaware.jasypt', name: 'jasypt-hibernate5', version: '1.9.2'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722'

        automationTestCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core:5.1.7.RELEASE'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    implementation 'ma.glasnost.orika:orika-core:1.5.4'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.1'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17'

    // swagger
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:$swaggerVersion")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:$swaggerVersion") {
        exclude module: 'swagger-annotations'
        exclude module: 'swagger-models'
    }
    compile("io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.21")
    compile("io.swagger:swagger-models:1.5.21")

    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.13.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.13.0'
}
```

When I run `gradle automationTest`I get this Error:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 18.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lmax/disruptor/SequenceReportingEventHandler
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1009)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses(Class.java:2155)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class$2.run(Class.java:1717)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class$2.run(Class.java:1712)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getClasses(Class.java:1711)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassInfoMap.registerClass(ClassInfoMap.java:48)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassInfoMap.<init>(ClassInfoMap.java:29)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassInfoMap.<init>(ClassInfoMap.java:21)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:436)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:338)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:179)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:613)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:178)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1275)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1251)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1100)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lmax.disruptor.SequenceReportingEventHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: The output shows that you have a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: I know that i have this Exception...... But When I run it without the testng.xm there is no such exception..... how can usage of testng.xml can casue such an Exception?
@KrishnanMahadevan

Comment: The difference is that when you are right clicking a TestNG suite xml file, then its the IDE that is running the TestNG tests and when you run it from the command line, its gradle that is running it. The problem in your case is that when you run via Gradle you are having problems. TestNG is not at fault and it doesnt even use that class as well.

Comment: Do you know how I can solve it? Is it a classpath missing? @ KrishnanMahadevan

Comment: Can you create a sample project that can be used to reproduce the problem (I think the most important thing here is to embed the gradle version to be used in your build file) and then share the project by attaching it to your question (or) upload to github and share a link to it by editing your question.